Regarding running docker on cloud9
I am trying to run docker for fastqc tool on aws cloud9 but it could not read the input file from s3 storage. It always showed that file does not exists or could not find.
docker run -v "s3://hnexom:data" quay.io/biocontainers/fastqc:0.11.9--0 fastqc "/data/AD0479_1T_R1.fastq.gz"
Skipping '/data/AD0479_1T_R1.fastq.gz' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
I would be greatful if someone help me regarding this.
Thanks & Regards,
Deepika

Are you sure you can use S3 in this way? It's not like a normal, local filesystem

no, i cant use. Would you please sugguest me that how can run docker on input files on s3 storage.

Try with Rclone, or S3fs-fuse
